# De que maneira posso reestruturar informações contidas um objeto do tipo list, em duas colunas?

Tags: r, lista

Considerando uma lista `x` composta por `n`vetores. Para ilustrar o problema  cogitei que tenha 3 elementos, como segue:

```
>x
$`2751006`
[1] 106.2  75.4  65.4  87.4  76.8 196.4  74.2

$`2751007`
[1]  73.9 110.1 101.3

$`2752006`
[1] 100.0 200.0
```

Como posso reestruturar a informação desta lista em `data.frame` de duas colunas de nomes X1 e X2:

```
X1      X2
106.2   2751006
75.4    2751006
65.4    2751006    
87.4    2751006
76.8    2751006
196.4   2751006
74.2    2751006
73.9    2751007
110.1   2751007
101.3   2751007
100.0   2752006   
200.0   2752006
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe uma função no base que faz exatamente isso, chamada `stack`. A parte mais difícil de usá-la é lembrar o nome, porque ela é bem incomum (fiquei 10 minutos procurando até achar...):

```
> li <- list(a = 1:3, b = 4:8, c = 9:10)
> li
$a
[1] 1 2 3

$b
[1] 4 5 6 7 8

$c
[1]  9 10

> stack(li)
   values ind
1       1   a
2       2   a
3       3   a
4       4   b
5       5   b
6       6   b
7       7   b
8       8   b
9       9   c
10     10   c
> unstack(stack(li))
$a
[1] 1 2 3

$b
[1] 4 5 6 7 8

$c
[1]  9 10
```

Comment: boa! com certeza esse é o melhor jeito de fazer!

Comment: Muito Bom!!! Obrigado, me ajudou muito.

Answer (score 3):

Outra forma de fazer isso é a seguinte:

```
> library(dplyr)
> x <- list(x = 1:3, y = 6:10, z = 8:13)
> lapply(x, function(x) data.frame(X1 = x)) %>% bind_rows(.id = "X2")
Source: local data frame [14 x 2]

      X2    X1
   (chr) (int)
1      x     1
2      x     2
3      x     3
4      y     6
5      y     7
6      y     8
7      y     9
8      y    10
9      z     8
10     z     9
11     z    10
12     z    11
13     z    12
14     z    13
```

A função `bind_rows` do `dplyr` tem o argumento `.id`, quando atribuímos a ele o nome de uma coluna, ele usa o identificador da lista como id de cada linha.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Valeu pela força.

Answer (score 3):

Você também pode usar a função `melt` do pacote `reshape2`.

Usando os mesmos dados do Molx:

```
li <- list(a = 1:3, b = 4:8, c = 9:10)
library(reshape2)
melt(li)
   value L1
1      1  a
2      2  a
3      3  a
4      4  b
5      5  b
6      6  b
7      7  b
8      8  b
9      9  c
10    10  c
```